# Change Culture language for a web reference

Tags: .net, web, reference, invalidoperationexception

I'm programming a new MVC 4 application. This must publish some data from the backoffice of the company. For now I'm only working local so this well make it easier, I tought.

This is the situation: My computer has a dutch language pack. What means I write the decimal like 25,58 instead of 25.58. Also the backoffice use this dutch language pack. The communication between the backoffice and the MVC is by a webservice.

So I made a Web References in VS2010. I also configered the web.config

```
<globalization culture="nl-BE" uiCulture="nl-BE"/>
```

In the code I make the request to the webservice like this

```
Comp.Backoffice obj = new Comp.Backoffice();
Comp.Backoffice.Company Company = obj.GetCompany(companyID);
```

And the problem now is, when I run the code and there is a decimal in the XML I get the error

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code Message There is an error in XML document (5, 219).
```

If I change the decimal 25,58 into 25.58. The error did not occur. So i think the webservice expect a decimal in English format.

Is this correct? And if so can I tell the code to expect a Dutch format?

Comment: What XML? Where is it located? How do you load it? What XML schema is it based on?

Comment: The XML is sent by the webservice.